# Using react router V6 Child component is not getting rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a following component where I am trying to use the React router.

```
const RouteList = [
  {
    path: "/",
    element: withSuspenseWrapper(SharedView),
    errorElement: withSuspenseWrapper(ErrorView),
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: withSuspenseWrapper(HomeView),
      },
      {
        path: "manageteam",
        element: withSuspenseWrapper(Manageteam),
        children: [
          {
            path: ':id',
            element: withSuspenseWrapper(ManageteamInfo),
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  }
];


function withSuspenseWrapper(Component) {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Loader loadingText="Preparing menu" />}>
      <Component />
    </Suspense>
  );
}
```

Here, When I am trying to go on the route `/manageteam/12` it does not render the respected component. still renders the `Manageteam` component and not the `ManageteamInfo` component.

Any idea regarding this ?

Comment: It's a child component, you have to add `<Outlet />` to the `Manageteam` so `ManageteamInfo` can be rendered

Comment: ahh @Konrad  right. One thing it shows both the components now in the /:id route, How do I show only that component ?

Answer (score 0):

These routes should be on the same level

```
const RouteList = [
  {
    path: "/",
    element: withSuspenseWrapper(SharedView),
    errorElement: withSuspenseWrapper(ErrorView),
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: withSuspenseWrapper(HomeView),
      },
      {
        path: "manageteam",
        children: [
          {
            index: true,
            element: withSuspenseWrapper(Manageteam),
          },
          {
            path: ":id",
            element: withSuspenseWrapper(ManageteamInfo),
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```